# Find the expected value of Y (Probability)

Tags: statistics

A discrete random variable Y has the following probability mass function f (y) = c(y − 3)2 for y = −2, −1, 0, 1, 2
where c is a constant.
(a) Find the value of c that make f a probability mass function. 
(b) Give the cumulative distribution function of Y .
(c) Find the expected value of Y . 
(d) Find the variance of Y .
(e) Let X = 1Y2 +2.1Y +3.4, find the expected value of X.

My question is for part c. I know that expected value is E[x] = mu*x = the sum of x*P(X=x). Or for this question in specific E[f(y)] = sum of f(y)p(y) but i can't seem to figure out what values to use in the equation to get a realistic number.

Comment: $E[Y]$ is the same thing as $E[y]$.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean. I don't know how to find E[y]...

Comment: $E(y) = \sum_{y=-2}^2 y f(y)$, you have the formula for $f(y)$. Use it and do this sum.